# Stuck in Error #1009 from 3 Days AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to prepare a multimeter. using rotate code i am moving the needle in my stage. then when it reaches a value a display is shown. now i have various values of resistances with me. so when i click on a particular resistance value initially it show show only the resistance and when the needle is rotated the resistance along with the value should be be displayed. I tried to run this code but getting Error #1009:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

Resistance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ResistanceMenu);
btn100Ohm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Ohm100Show);
function Ohm100Show(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(15);
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownOK);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpOK);

function ResistanceMenu(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(10);
}

function mouseDownOK (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, rotateOK);
}

function rotateOK (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var angle:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - needle.y, mouseX - needle.x);
    angle = angle * 180/Math.PI-90;
    needle.rotation = angle;

    Ohm_200.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Ohm_200Call);
    function Ohm_200Call (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndPlay(20);
    }
}

function mouseUpOK (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, rotateOK);
}
```

the rotate part is running properly. but when i add the listener for btn100Ohm i get the error #1009

Kindly help me

Comment: You might want to bookmark the following link - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html

Answer (score 0):

you are probably trying to access the button (btn100Ohm) before it has been created. I don't know how (or where) you have your code and buttons, but that error 1009 means the button doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

From ActionScript 3 documentation ([Run-Time Errors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html)):

> #### #1009 - *null has no properties.*
>
> An object that evaluates to null can have no properties. This error
>   can occur in some unexpected (though valid) situations. For example,
>   consider the following code, which creates a Sprite object. Since this
>   Sprite object is never added to the display list (via the *`addChild()`*
>   method of a DisplayObjectContainer object), then its *`stage`* property is
>   set to null, and as such, its *`stage`* property cannot have any
>   properties. So the code generates the errror:
>
> `import flash.display.Sprite;`
>   `var sprite1:Sprite = new Sprite();`
>   `var q:String = sprite1.stage.quality;`